# How to prevent dotted rectangle around navbar-brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and have a navbar link like this

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"> My Site</a>
```

I have a custom css

```
.navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-brand:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,0,0,0.85);
}
```

I am not able do following:

- On any browser, reset the link to original state when clicked. The color of text remains the color of hover specification. I need to it reset to original state.
- Only on FIREFOX, there is a dotted rectangle around `.navbar-brand` when clicked. Its not there on CHROME, SAFARI.

Can you please provide pointers?

Comment: Remove the :focus selector on the CSS declaration ... and for firefox set the outline on focus to 0.

Comment: thank you all it works. I will accept first answer received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an outline to show that an element is focused. It is set by this rule:

```
a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

You can change it by adding the following rule:

```
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
a:focus {
    outline: none !important;

}
```